# How to move a document from SharePoint 2016 document library to SharePoint 2010 document library?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepointdocumentlibrary

I have a scenario where user will add new document in to SharePoint 2016 document library once document been uploaded automatically the same document copy should be added in SharePoint 2010 document library.
**example:**
**SP2010: http://domainA:100/sites/nagarajan
SP2016: http://domainB:200/sites/users**

through code or any scripting is possible to achieve this please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

We can create an event receiver for SharePoint 2016 document library, and then copy the document to SharePoint 2010 document library.

If the SP2016 and SP2010 are not in the same domain, we can use CSOM(C#) to add the document to SharePoint 2010 library in the event receiver.

References:

[How to: Create an event receiver](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/sharepoint/how-to-create-an-event-receiver)

[Uploading a file into a library via CSOM, even if the library does not exist](https://piasys.com/blog/uploading-a-file-into-a-library-via-csom-even-if-the-library-does-not-exist/)